# how to get back index.html page from a second html page using python3 and flask?

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask, href

I have a basic python3 script in a main folder:

```py
from flask import Flask,render_template
app=Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
app.run(debug=True)
```

A simple `index.html` file in `templates` folder:

```html
<!doctype html>
    </head>
    <body>                
        <a href="static/cv.html">GOT TO CV</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

It works perfectly and opens `cv.html` in `static` folder:

```html
<a href="index.html">BACK</a>
```

But this command in `cv.html` doesn't work.

The error message says:

```
"GET /static/index.html HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Looks like `index.html` should be in `static` folder.

How could i get back `index.html` page from main folder?

Comment: you will need to use the route's path that serves the `index.html` template, which is `/`. so: `<a href="/">BACK</a>`